Can we configure webhooks in Magento using its REST API
I'm currently exploring the capabilities of Magento's REST API for integrating with external systems, and I'm interested in setting up webhooks to receive real-time notifications for specific events occurring within my Magento store.
I understand that Magento provides a comprehensive REST API for managing various aspects of the store, but I'm unsure about the specific capabilities and procedures for configuring webhooks using this API.
Could someone please clarify whether it's possible to configure webhooks in Magento using its REST API? If so, I'd appreciate any guidance or resources on how to implement webhook subscriptions, manage event notifications, and handle webhook payloads effectively within the Magento ecosystem.
Additionally, I'd like to know if there are any best practices or considerations to keep in mind when working with webhooks in Magento, such as security measures, performance optimizations, or compatibility concerns with different Magento versions.
Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you can provide!

The webhooks documentation with examples: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/extensibility/webhooks/
There is no way to configure webhooks using Rest API at the moment.
You can configure webhooks via XML in the webhooks.xml file or the Admin UI https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/extensibility/webhooks/admin-configuration/.
As webhooks are synchronous they can affect the performance of your application as the application will be waiting for the response from the webhook endpoint. You can consider using eventing if your action can be performed asynchronously https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/extensibility/events/.
Regarding the security measures, you can implement:

authorization headers
IP whitelisting
signature verification


Thank you for your insights. Unfortunately, manual configuration isn't feasible for my use case. I need to automate the creation of webhooks from an external system
